# Is it possible to create an array of errors in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, error-handling, nestjs

To provide some context first, here's an example payload:

```typescript
{ 
"productType": 2,
"colorId": 43,
"categoryId": 23,
}
```

Let's say that I have a product creation method that makes 3 different calls, each one sending an id,

1. One to check if a product type exists.
2. One to check if a selected color exists.
3. One to check if a product category exists.

All of those calls must return something (an object) if the id is valid, if it's not, it should throw an error, but here's the thing: What if I need to make all those calls first, and for each time the application cannot find a given id, I add an error message to an array of strings and after all those calls are made, I return something.

So if the product type 2 and the color 43 are not on the database, but the category 23 is, it should return something like this:

```typescript
['Could not find product type with id: 2', 'Could not find color with id: 43']
```

This leaves me with two questions:

**First one**: Is it possible to set a dynamic promise without using Promise? Something like this:

```typescript
createProduct(): Promise<StringArray[] || ProductObject> {
   return either_an_array or an_object
}
```

**Second:**
How should I create that array of errors and how should I add errors to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, issue of data type in Promise:
You don 't have to return the error type specifically. You can just throw an error and catch it in the function where you are calling `createProduct` function.

Second, calling multiple APIs in createProduct
function and generate the error array.
you can use trycatch here as well along with async/await.

So your function will somthing look this

```
async createProduct(): Promise <ProductObject> {
    let errors: string[];
    try {
        const productTypeExist = await checkIfProductTypeExist();
    } catch (typeErr) {
        errors.push(typeErr);
    }

    try {
        const colorExist = await checkIfColorExist();
    } catch (coloreErr) {
        errors.push(coloreErr);
    }

    try {
        const catExist = await checkIfCategoryExist();
    } catch (catErr) {
        errors.push(catErr);
    }

    if (errors.length) {
        throw Error(errors)
    }

    // if everything goes well
    return product_object;
}
```

On top of this, if you are using the latest node.js. you can explore `Promise.allSettled` which will allow you to call all those functions in parallel and fetch errors at once.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about the allSettled method, thanks!
About those try/catch... Isn't it against best practices to use so many try/catch on a single function? Couldn't it be done in less lines?

Comment: Yes, definitely you can improve it to include all functions in a single try-catch. The only issue is it will return the first error and need to find another approach to returning an array of all errors.